# Splitting a line in c++ on comments

Tags: c++, string, parsing

I'm working on a class project in C++, I need to write a function that will grab the comments in code and insert them into a vector. The text file that the function receives is split line by line, I am thinking of using `.find()` and `.substr()` but I do not sure how the `substr()` method works here is what I think would work.

```
string comment = split.substr(0,split[i].find(inLineComment));
```

I'm not sure though, would the `(0,...)` make the string split from the beginning to the comment character? Can anyone clarify?

I am also not sure how I would get the comment code from block comments as I only have `.find(inLineComment)` for inline comment characters. Some suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: `cppreference.com` is great for finding the answer to these types of questions. It documents all of the standard library. Here is the page on [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) and here is the page on [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).

Comment: Add same text with a few comments

Answer (score 0):

Suppose what your function received is stored in `split`, with multiple lines of text. `split[0]` is the first line, `split[1]` the second, and so on.

First of all, your question could be divided into two parts:

## 1. Grabbing single-line comments

To grab a single-line comment, identify the comment section with double adjacent slashes `//`. You could parse through every line in a for loop,
`for(int i=0; i<split.size(); i++)`. And inside of the loop, check every line if it contains the identifier `//`:

```
int pos = split[i].find("//");
if (pos != string::npos)
    string comment = split[i].substr(pos+2);
```

For you information, `string::npos` is the value `find()` function return if it didn't find the keyword. (see [cpp reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)) 
The reason I put a **+2** in `substr()` function is because that `find()` returns the first character of the input substring, and in this case, it is the first slash `/`.

## 2. Grabbing multiple-line comments

Multiple-line comments are a little bit complicated, since we could only recognize the identifier `/*` and `*/`, and we couldn't see any difference in the context within the two of them.

Fortunately, we could overcome this by simply using a variable `bool inComment` to keep track of `/*` and `*/`: When we meet `/*`, we then set `inComment` flag on; upon seeing `*/`, we then set the flag off.

But the problem is that, there might be more than one `/*` and `*/` in a single line! So we need to extract the contents recursively: After finding `/*`, we search for `*/`. If we found it in the same line, then we move the searching scope backward, and then we search for `/*` again, and so on. This can be achieved through a while loop. Here's the code:

```
string sub = split[i];
if (! inComment){
    int start, end;
    while ((start=sub.find("/*")) != string::npos){
        sub = sub.substr(start+2);  // move backward
        int end = sub.find("*/");
        if (end != string::npos){
            comment = sub.substr(0, end);
            sub = sub.substr(end+2);  // move backward
            // inComment remains false
        }else {
            comment = sub;
            inComment = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}else {
    int start;
    int end = sub.find("*/");
    if (end != string::npos){
        comment = sub.substr(0, end);
        sub = sub.substr(end+2);  // move backward
        inComment = false;

        while ((start=sub.find("/*")) != string::npos){
            sub = sub.substr(start+2);  // move backward
            end = sub.find("*/");
            if (end != string::npos){
                comment = sub.substr(0, end);
                sub = sub.substr(end+2);  // move backward
                // inComment remains false
            }else {
                comment = sub;
                inComment = true;
                break;
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

Note that I stored the whole line in a temporary string called `sub` in the beginning. After extracting each piece of comment, the scope of `sub` was updated so that the next `find()` function could search behind recursively.
The key role of this piece of code is the variable `inComment`, which controls the flow of execution between the two if else block.

Answer (score -1):

This is the function signature:

```
string substr (size_t pos = 0, size_t len = npos) const;
```

Meaning is, takes the string and starts at the pos' element. 
And passes len element. Then stop and trim that part. Make the new string. 
Return it. You can check the link below to see the example:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/